# Why in Ruby Object's singleton_class isn't Class?

Tags: ruby, singleton, superclass

I am a little confused, why is the super class of the singleton class using is_a? method but return false?

I

```
class Animal
end

obj = Animal.new
singleton = (class<<obj;self;end)

p singleton.ancestors , singleton.is_a?(Animal) 

#[#<Class:#<Animal:0x00000000060105d0>>, Animal, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
#false
```

I think it shall return true.

Experienced experts please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking whether the singleton class is an animal. But the singleton class is not an animal, it is a class, i.e. it is an instance of the `Class` class, not the `Animal` class.

This is no different from any other class. For example `1` is an instance of `Integer`, but `Integer` is not an instance of `Numeric`, it is an instance of `Class`. `Integer.is_a?(Numeric)` would be `false`, since `Integer` is *not* an instance of `Numeric`, it is a *subclass* of `Numeric`.

Comment: is object's singleton class an instance of singleton class? `Animal.new.singleton_class.is_a?(Animal.singleton_class) #=> true`

Comment: @Alex, one cannot create an instance of a singleton class.

Comment: That's why its called a singleton class, you can just inject or modify in real time but no instance. Its "hidden" for saying in some way..